# Using virtualenv on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I have been struggling with setting up virtualenv and pip on Mac OS X Yosemite. I keep running into the same problem:

```
$ virtualenv foobar
New python executable in foobar/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/name/foobar/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools

  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
...
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
          with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
      IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py'

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==12.0.7', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
....
    OSError: Command /Users/name/foobar/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 2
```

Does anyone know what is causing this problem or how I can get around it. I have tried various versions of installing virtualenv and pip locally/globally to no avail.

Comment: I set up a fresh machine with Yosemite earlier today, following the instructions at http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/ and https://github.com/1st/python-on-osx. Have you installed Python separately, or are you using the preinstalled version?

Comment: I haven't installed python - using the native 2.7 installation. I think :)

Comment: I suggest that you install homebrew and use it to install the latest versions of Python - see the articles I linked to.

Comment: I suggest homebrew too. Attached is another link which is very similar to the two above, but sometimes looking at multiple instructions can help: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/. As noted on the page "Homebrew installs Setuptools..." which looks like it will solve one of the issues you're running into `setuptools pip failed with error code 2`

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I didn't suceeed on the machine in question, but following the linked steps on a fresh install on another machine seems to be going swimmingly. Seems I must have corrupted something on the other machine - maybe overwritten installation or something. I think I will just start from scratch. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This likely means you don't have `pip` installed in your system python environment. `virtualenv` depends on `pip`, so it was trying to be helpful and install it for you (and failing, because it couldn't write to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`).

Try installing pip into your system python first (with `sudo`):

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

After that, `virtualenv` should be able to work without `sudo`-ing.